# JNI multiple variables

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am using JNI by passing many variables from Java to C

```
public native int[] intArrayMethod(int[] t,int nbr,int tag);
```

How can I use these variables in C?
I have generated the header file and i obtained:

```
#ifndef _Included_MainClass
#define _Included_MainClass

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif

/*
 Class:     MainClass
 Method:    intArrayMethod
 Signature: ([FII)[I
*/

    JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_MainClass_intArrayMethod
        (JNIEnv *, jobject, jfloatArray, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

How to use the variables passed in my C code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your java method and JNI method signatures don't match. ( int[] and jfloatArray). Use javah to generate the signature. It saves a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

- Write a .c file to match - same header, but with a body {} and parameter names.
- do something with the variables
- return the result

Code:

```
#include "foo.h"
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_MainClass_intArrayMethod 
(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jfloatArray arr, jint a, jint b) {

     jintArray ret[2];
     ret[0] = a + b;
     ret[1] = arr[0] + arr[1];
     return ret;
}
```

Compile it with something like this:

```
gcc -shared foo.c -I/path/to/java/include -o libfoo.so
```

Don't forget to include a load line in your Java code:

```
static {
   System.loadLibrary("foo"); // does not include lib prefix, or .dll/.so suffix!
}
```

Run with this, (assuming libfoo.so in current directory).

```
java -Djava.library.path=. Foo
```